# What textbooks would you recommend to learn quantum systems engineering?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, resource-recommendations, quantum-computer, electrical-engineering

I am a first-year undergraduate doing a BA in Physics. I have studied quantum mechanics at the rudimentary level, and as far as my mathematical background is concerned: I know linear algebra and ordinary differential equations. There was a very interesting course called Introduction to Quantum Systems Engineering which had the following description:

> "Introduction to the quantum mechanics needed to engineer quantum systems for computation, communication, and sensing. Topics include motivation for quantum engineering, qubits and quantum gates, rules of quantum mechanics, mathematical background, quantum electrical circuits and other physical quantum systems, harmonic and anharmonic oscillators, measurement, the Schrödinger equation, noise, entanglement, benchmarking, quantum communication, and quantum algorithms."

What textbooks would you recommend to learn this course?

Comment: Perhaps you could ask the instructor of this course.

Comment: This course is not offered at my university. Its offered in an undergraduate program of another university I saw online.

Comment: depends a bit on what exactly you mean with "quantum systems engineering", but you might find useful references in https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1367/55 and links therein